# tumblr text posts overlapping

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I am new to creating themes and have created a [side blog](https://uchihasasu.tumblr.com/) for practice. I'm not sure why but the text posts seem to be overlapping each other, and then conflicting with other posts as well as the pagination at the bottom right corner. I'm not sure how to fix this issue, and I'm not sure what's causing it.

Here's the CSS for the tumble blog theme.

```
<style type="text/css">

/***SIDEBAR***/
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 270px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#description {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}


/***GENERIC***/
body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: 'Yeon Sung';
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9f815d;
    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
a:hover {
    color: #c0c0c0;
}

b, strong {
    color: #9f665d;
}

i, em {
    color: #9a9f5d;
}

blockquote {
    padding: 2px 7px;
    margin: 3px 0 3px 8px;
    border-left: 1px dotted #c0c0c0;
}
blockquote img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'UnifrakturMaguntia';
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}

#links {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 5%;
}
#links a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    padding: 2%;
    
   -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
#links a:hover {
    color: #c0c0c0;
}


/***POSTS***/
.container {
    padding:10px;
    width:500px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:60px;
}

.posts {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-left: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/***PERMALINKS & TAGS***/
.permalinks {
    text-align: center;
}
.permalinks a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
}
.permalinks a:hover {
    color: #5d9e9f;
}

.tags {
    text-align: center;
}
.tags a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
}
.tags a:hover {
    color: #715d9f;
}

/***PAGINATION***/
#pagination {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 100px;
}
#pagination a {
    color: #3a3a3a;
    font-size: 18px;
    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
#pagination a:hover {
    color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">

<!---SIDEBAR--->
<div id="sidebar">
<h1>{Title}</h1>

<div id="description">{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}</div>

<div id="links">
    <a href="/">home</a>
    <a href="/ask">ask</a>
    <a href="/archive">archive</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a></div></div>

<!---POSTS--->   
{block:Posts}<div class="posts">

{block:Text}{block:Title}{Title}{/block:Title}{Body}{/block:Text}

{block:Photo}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Photo}

{block:Panorama}{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>{LinkCloseTag}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Panorama}

{block:Photoset}{Photoset}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Photoset}

{block:Quote}"{Quote}"{block:Source}{Source}{/block:Source}{/block:Quote}

{block:Link}<a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}>{Name}</a>{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}{/block:Link}

{block:Chat}{block:Title}{Title}</a>{/block:Title}
{block:Lines}<li>{block:Label}{Label}{/block:Label}{Line}</li>{/block:Lines}{/block:Chat}
                        
{block:Video}{Video-500}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Video}

{block:Audio}{AudioEmbed}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Audio}

<!---PERMALINK & TAGS--->
<div class="permalinks"><a href="{permalink}">{DayOfMonth}{DayOfMonthSuffix} {ShortMonth} {Year} </a><a href="{permalink}">{block:NoteCount}{NoteCount}{/block:NoteCount}</a></div><div class="tags">{block:HasTags}{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}"> {Tag}{/block:Tags}</a></div>

</div>{/block:Posts}
    
</div>
    
<!---PAGINATION--->
<div id="pagination">{block:Pagination}
{block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}">prev</a>{/block:PreviousPage}
{block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}">next</a>{/block:NextPage}
{/block:Pagination}</div> 
    
{block:ContentSource}
<!-- {SourceURL}{block:SourceLogo}<img src="{BlackLogoURL}"
width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />
{/block:SourceLogo}
{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo} -->
{/block:ContentSource}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you might not have a correctly closed tag somewhere. Your posts should output inside a loop., but on your page there are several pagination blocks which have a unique id (id's should only exist on the page once). Is the code in the example above identical to the one on your blog?

Comment: @lharby, thank you, i will check if i missed any closing tags or incorrectly placed them. also, yes this code is identical to the one on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have found your issue.

Inside some of the tumblr template blocks there are a couple of anomalies and I think you have to move the `{block:Posts}` inside the wrapper, although I have not tested this.

Firstly there is a closing a tag with no opening tag `</a>`.

Also this might not be a deal clincher but the double quote marks might not be rendered properly. See attached image.

```
{block:Quote}"{Quote}"{block:Source}{Source}{/block:Source}{/block:Quote}
{block:Link}<a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}>{Name}</a>{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}{/block:Link}
{block:Chat}{block:Title}{Title}</a>{/block:Title}{block:Lines}<li>{block:Label}{Label}{/block:Label}{Line}</li>{/block:Lines}{/block:Chat}
```

And the block should be rendered inside the wrapper I believe so instead of

```
{block:Posts}
<div class="posts">
    ...
</div>
{/block:Posts}
```

It should be

```
<div class="posts">
{block:Posts}
    ...
{/block:Posts}
</div>
```

Hopefully that will work, but check Tumblr documentation for block examples.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and just figured it out using this tut: https://viwan-th.tumblr.com/post/46016724933

CSS:

```
#wrap {width:520px; margin:auto;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
{block:Posts}
...post stuff...
{/block:Posts}
</div>
```

Comment: If I were you I would just not mention the tutorial at all. Just provide an answer of your own.

Comment: @Dharman I didn't come up with it at all. I'm not going to just steal code and claim it as my own.